# Create a validation that will not fire unless the amount is greater than 0

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to create a validation rule that will fire when the Amount_1  is greater than or less than Amount_2 but not when Amount_1 = 0

```
Amount_1 <> Amount_2
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You should show us what you've tried so far, and point to a specific place that you're stuck on. You can include that in your question by making an [edit]. Even if what you have doesn't work, showing us what you have allows people to make answers that are more tailored to your particular situation. If you're getting an error message, you should include it verbatim.

Comment: Also - have you checked the [Validation Rules Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/validation-rules/get-started-with-validation-rules)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a validation rule that will fire when the `Amount_1` is greater than or less than `Amount_2` but not when `Amount_1 = 0`, you can use the following formula:

```
AND(
    Amount_1__c <> 0,
    Amount_1__c <> Amount_2__c
)
```

This formula checks if the `Amount_1` field is not equal to zero and not equal to the Amount_2` field. If both conditions are true, the validation rule will fire and display an error message.

Comment: Thank you! that worked!